# generator html and css

Tags: html, css

There is a webapp or software that to speed up the work of writing html markup and css?
example:

1. after importing the mokup site (jpg) created from the graph, with the tools provided by the application, follow in the box that will make the site
2. export your work to html + css.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Usually Stack Overflow is designed to have developers trouble shoot broken code. Including an example of your non-functioning code helps. This is probably why you're getting down-voted.

I think you're looking for an HTML editor? There are countless editors, just search for one.

Comment: Have you done any research on this? Looks like you want software to automate the process of building a whole website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following sites:

**[Flavors.me](http://flavors.me/)**

**[Adobe Muse](http://www.adobe.com/products/muse.html)**

**[Wix.com](http://www.wix.com/)**

Of Course there are limitations when you use tools like that... If you are not fussy with the result and you are not willing to dive into coding the above will do the job for you, just drag and drop and configure.

Hope this helps